# Debugging "Error setting nil" in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this piece of Elisp code in my Emacs configuration file:

```
(when (string= (getenv "TERM") "screen")
  (custom-set-variables
   (custom-set-faces
    '(font-lock-comment-face ((((class color)
                                (min-colors 8)
                                (background dark))
                                (foreground red)))))))
```

When I start Emacs I get `Error setting nil: (setting-constant nil)` from this code. Though it seems to work fine I'm aware that this might be a sign of some hidden problem. I don't know Elisp too well thus I need help. Can anyone offer an explanation of this error and tell me how to eliminate it? I'm using Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: It would help if you were to detail your exact requirement for this. It looks like you wish comments to be coloured differently when you are running Emacs within `screen` -- but **not** when you are running Emacs in a terminal which *isn't* running `screen`. Is that correct? I'm slightly curious as to why, but more interested in whether you *actually* want different behaviour in different terminals, or if you *always* use `screen` and are simply using that as a way to say "I'm in a terminal".

Comment: I always run Emacs inside a Tmux session in a console. The problem is that Tmux and Emacs don't seem to go well together - Emacs behaves differently in terms of UI colours and keyboard shortcuts inside Tmux session and in a plain console. This here is a hack to fix comment colour inside Tmux and - as far as end effect is concerned - it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a lot wrong with that, I'm afraid.

1. `custom-set-faces` and `custom-set-variables` are two separate forms; you shouldn't be calling one inside the other.
2. You shouldn't be wrapping a call to *either* of those functions in a conditional expression. Both forms are generated and updated automatically when you use the `customize` interface, and Emacs won't find them if they're not top-level forms in your init file. Which means it will create an *additional* copy of each one when it needs to. Which leads to...
3. You mustn't have multiple instances of these forms. In fact Emacs includes the following warning comments when it generates the form:

   ```
   ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
   ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
   ```

   Right now you are encouraging that situation to occur.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a lot of problems. The question is what is the correct way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: A caveat is that I only make limited use of the customize mechanisms myself, and so I am taking issues 2&3 at face-value. It's *possible* that it's actually ok to do. Issue 1 looks likely to be the actual cause of the error, so for starters you could delete `(custom-set-variables` and its closing parenthesis.